# Excel replace with advanced if (multiple conditions)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column in Excel with over 10,000 cells of data. They have the following four different data:

```
PC is online(connected)
PC is down(notconnected)
PC is down(disabled)
PC is down(other-disabled)
```

From this, I wish to create a formula so that I can transform this data to the following:

```
Connected
Not Connected
Disabled
Disabled
```

How to do this so I can do it in one column?

Comment: =IF(A1="PC is online(connected)","Connected",IF(A1="PC is online(connected)","Disconnected"))... just add the remaining conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a lookup table for that, and put on cell `F2` the following formula:

```
=XLOOKUP(A2:A10,C2:C5,D2:D5, "CASE NOT DEFINED")
```

and here is the output:

[image: sample excel file]

For safety purpose added as a last resort the scenario: `CASE NOT DEFINED` to identify any values not defined.

If your excel version doesn't support `XLOOKUP` then you can use the following instead:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A10,C2:D5, 2,0), "CASE NOT DEFINED")
```